# Terraform apply with '-replace' parameter doesn't force replace the object

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In my terraform definitions, I have EC2 defined:

```
resource "aws_instance" "eventhub_instance" {
  ami                         = var.eh_instance_ami
  instance_type               = var.eh_instance_type
  count                       = 2
......
```

Those instances are up and running. Now, I want to run `terraform apply` and force recreation of those instances. My understanding that I can use `-replace=ADDRESS` to force that, so I tried:

```
terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file=vars/dev.terraform.tfvars -replace=aws_instance.eventhub_instance[0] -replace=aws_instance.eventhub_instance[1]
```

Terraform runs and finishes with

```
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
```

Why doesn't it replace/recreate the EC2 instances?

Comment: The namespacing for the resources is possibly incorrect. Verify the correct nomenclature by checking your state.

Comment: Try this with `terraform taint`. If that succeeds, then you may need to raise an issue on the tracker,

Comment: @MattSchuchard actually, you were right - i replaced the address with 'module.all.aws_instance.eventhub_instance[0]' (adding module.all) and it started working. If you want to put your suggestion into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `-replace=` argument returns `No changes` during a `plan` or `apply`, then it is possible the namespace of the referenced resource is incorrect. You can doublecheck this with the deprecated `terraform taint` command.

The nomenclature of a resource within a module requires the namespace prefix `module.<declared module name>`. In your situation where the declared module name is `all`, that would then be:

```
terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file=vars/dev.terraform.tfvars -replace=module.all.aws_instance.eventhub_instance[0] -replace=module.all.aws_instance.eventhub_instance[1]
```